# How to have chromium appear as chrome to web sites?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, skype

I would like to use skype on an old netbook with a 32bit-only atom processor (N270).

The skype linux client is only available for 64 bit linuxes. But they have a web app. However, their web app is only supported for the browsers "Edge" and "Chrome".

Edge is a windows browser and does not run on linux. Chrome is no longer available for 32 bit linux. But Chromium is. As far as I understand, Chromium is the same as Chrome except for some additional Google integration.

Skype web service actually starts with Chromium and lets me log into my account, I get much farther with it than with Firefox, which is immediately blocked by Skype web. However, I cannot participate in audio and video calls with chromium, the buttons for initiating them are greyed out, and a tool-tip says "Audio and video calls are not supported on your browser."

My question is can I make Chromium more appear like Chrome to circumvent this not-Chrome detection and hopefully use Skype on this otherwise unused old netbook (The processor is an Atom N270 and does *not* support 64bits).

Comment: Look among your available browser extensions for a "User Agent Switcher". It will change how your browser is detected by others.

Comment: Have you been able to enable audio\video calling in Chromium?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov No. At least, not yet.

Comment: I am working again these days to enable audio/video on a 32bit Ubuntu (Atom N270), I will tell if any news. Until now I found that it is about allowing some cookies to enable images and notifications.